# data from database with foreach - from top to down

Tags: php, foreach

database:

```
id | name
1  | aaa
2  | bbb
3  | ccc
.. | ...
250| zz3

foreach ($datafromdb as $value){
  echo $value->name();
}
```

this show me:

```
aaa bbb  ccc  ... zz3
```

from left to right

```
if 

<table>
 <tr>
    foreach ($datafromdb as $value){
      echo '<td>' . $value->name() . '</td>';
    }
  </tr>
</table>
```

show:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
...
zzz3
```

how can i make table 12x12 ?

```
aaa aaa1 bbb2
bbb aaa2 bbb2
... aaa3 bbb3
... ...  ....
zzz zzz2 zzz4
```

first from top to down (12x), then next column and again from top to down (12x) etc 12x

i have  show this value from left to right, left to right, left to right etc, but i would like from top to down, top to down, top to down etc

Comment: Can you guarantee there are 144 records in the database if not what is the behaviour with more than 12x12 records

Comment: The output of the second snippet should also show the values in a row.  Or do you actually have `tr` inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel Cherrington's code is good, but with only PHP just do:

```
<?php
$data = range(1,240);
$tab = array();
$max = 12;
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data);$i++){
    $tab[($i % $max)][] = $data[$i];
}

echo "<table border='1'>";
foreach($tab as $line){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($line as $row){
        echo "<td>".$row."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
        $index=0;
        foreach ($datafromdb as $value)
        {
          if($index%12==0) echo '<tr>' ;
          echo '<td>' . $value->name() . '</td>';
          if($index%12==0) echo '</tr>' ;
        }
</table>
```

Comment: this show me value from left to right, left to right, left to right etc, but i would like from top to down, top to down, top to down etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating tables side by side (float them using css)

```
  $index=0;
    foreach ($data as $value)
    {
      if($index == '12') $index = 0;

      if($index == 0) echo '<table style="float:left;">';
      echo '<tr>' ;
      echo '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
      echo '</tr>' ;
      if($index==11) echo '</table>' ;
      $index ++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look, I don't exactly know php but this is what I can think of:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    var counter=0;
    foreach ($datafromdb as $value){
        if (i%12==0) { echo '<td>'; }
        echo $value->name()+'<br/>';
        if (i%12==0) { echo '</td>'; }
        counter++;
    }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this show me value from left to right, left to right, left to right etc, but i would like from top to down, top to down, top to down etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = range(1,16);

$maxColumns = 4;
$maxRows = 4;

?>

<table>

    <? for($r = 0; $r < $maxRows; $r++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <? for($c = 0; $c < $maxColumns; $c++) { ?>
                <td><? echo $data[($c*$maxColumns)+$r]?></td>
            <? }?>
        </tr>
    <? } ?>
</table>
```

You might want to check if the data actually exists before echoing it.