# Display mysql results with php in columns and sorted per column

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code to display some brands per category.

```
<?
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","baba","passsss");//database connection
mysql_select_db("gr_brands_igi") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);     
$query = "SELECT * FROM brands ORDER BY category_anchor ASC, brand_anchor ASC";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$lasteventname = "";

echo "<table border='0' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
$cell_ctr = 0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row[0] != $lasteventname){
        $title = $row[0];
        $lasteventname = $row[0];
        echo "<tr><td colspan=5><h2>$title</h2></td></tr>";
    }
    if(($cell_ctr % 5) == 4) // 2 is the number of columns
    {
        echo"</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        $cell_ctr = 0;
    }
  echo "<td align='justify' cellspacing='2' cellpadding='2'>";
  echo "<h3><a href='http://www.example.com/search/search.asp?txtsearch=$row[2]&catg=$row[3]&intitleanddesc=1&isnavbarsearch=1&gallery=1'>" . $row[2] . "</a></h3>";
  echo "</td>";
  $cell_ctr++;
}

if($cell_ctr == 1)
{
  echo "</tr>";
}
else if($cell_ctr == 2)
{
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo"</table>";
?>
```

right now it displays this

Jewels

- 1 2
- 3 4
- 5 6
- 7 8

But i want to order it per column like this:

Jewels

- 1 5
- 2 6
- 3 7
- 4 8

The fields in the database are:

```
category_anchor
keyword
brand_anchor
category_id
```

I have only one while loop and with the $lasteventname i print the category only once

Any Ideas?

Comment: Take a look at - [stackoverflow.com/questions/6938094/data-from-database-with-foreach-from-top-to-down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938094/data-from-database-with-foreach-from-top-to-down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it need to be a table ? for my idea i will do with list items

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $i = 0;

    echo '<ul>';

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      if (($i % 4) == 0 && $i > 0) {
        echo '</ul><ul>';
      }
      echo '<li><h3>your code</h3></li>';
      $i++;
    }

    echo '</ul>';

    ?>
```

the result will be like this, then you can style it like table as you want

```
<div class="banner">
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The trouble is to display the category title (category) and underneath the values of each category.

Right now i have this: if($row[0] != $lasteventname){
        $title = $row[0];
        $lasteventname = $row[0];
        echo "<tr><td colspan=5><h2>$title</h2></td></tr>";
    }

To Show the category once

Comment: You can put a another li with class like <li class="title"></li> and this will have css clear:both property, if can not make it work please comment back