# How to display a list in three columns using php?

Tags: php, html, html-table

For the past couple of hours, I've been unsuccessfully trying to figure out the php code to display a list in three columns so that it has this order

```
A D G
B E H
C F I
```

but I'm really lost. Can anyone help me with this?
I currently only have code that lists in this order

```
A B C
D E F
G H I
```

This is my current code:

```
echo '<table><tr>';
foreach ($categories as $k => $category) {
    if ($k % 3 == 0 && $k ! = 0) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
    echo '<td><a href="category.php?category='.$category["id"].'">'.$category["category"].'</a></td>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Will those always be the numbers used?

Comment: Actually, in usage, they will only be letters.

Comment: Check out [stackoverflow.com/questions/6938094/data-from-database-with-foreach-from-top-to-down#6938762](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938094/data-from-database-with-foreach-from-top-to-down#6938762).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$columns = 3;
$rows = ceil(count($categories) / $columns);

echo '<table>';

for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) {
    echo '<tr>';

    foreach ($categories as $k => $category) {
        if ($k % $rows == $row) {
            echo '<td><a href="category.php?category='.$category["id"].'">'.$category["category"].'</a></td>';
        }
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

It's not very efficient, but right now I can't think on a better way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works great! My dataset is not that large so it should be good.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have the list *rendered* in columns as indicated, you could generate it in the logical order and just uses the CSS `columns` property to set in columns:

```
ul {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
}
```

The bad news is that this is not supported by IE 9 and earlier, but the Columns polyfills like [css3-multi-column.js](http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/) might work sufficiently well in simple cases (despite their limitations and issues).

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, and I am posting my answer to this old question for the following reasons:

1. My answer is more general and easy for others to adapt.
2. My array was associative, with a string key. BTW, my answer will work for both associative and indexed arrays.
3. I didn't want a complex CSS solution, like some of the other answers on this topic. Actually, the solution I came up with was pretty simple--use multiple  tags with style="float:left", inside of a giant table. While I was sceptical that having multiple tbody tags in a single table would pass HTML validation, it in fact did pass without errors.

Some things to note:

- **$numCols** is your desired number of columns.
- Since we are floating items, you may need to set the width and min-width of parent elements and/or add some <br style="clear: both" />, based on your situation.
- for alternative sorting methods, see http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Here is my full answer:

```
function sortVertically( $data = array() )
{
    /* PREPARE data for printing */
    ksort( $data );     // Sort array by key.
    $numCols    = 3;    // Desired number of columns
    $numCells   = is_array($data) ? count($data) : 1 ;
    $numRows    = ceil($numCells / $numCols);
    $extraCells = $numCells % $numCols;  // Store num of tbody's with extra cell
    $i          = 0;    // iterator
    $cCell      = 0;    // num of Cells printed
    $output     = NULL; // initialize 


    /* START table printing */
    $output     .= '<div>';
    $output     .= '<table>';

    foreach( $data as $key => $value )
    {
        if( $i % $numRows === 0 )   // Start a new tbody
        {
            if( $i !== 0 )          // Close prev tbody
            {
                $extraCells--;
                if ($extraCells === 0 )
                {
                    $numRows--;     // No more tbody's with an extra cell
                    $extraCells--;  // Avoid re-reducing numRows
                }
                $output .= '</tbody>';
            }

            $output .= '<tbody style="float: left;">';
            $i = 0;                 // Reset iterator to 0
        }
        $output .= '<tr>';
            $output .= '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
            $output .= '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        $output .= '</tr>';

        $cCell++;                   // increase cells printed count
        if($cCell == $numCells){    // last cell, close tbody
            $output .= '</tbody>';
        }

        $i++;
    }

    $output .= '</table>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    return $output;
}
```

I hope you find this answer useful.